# Do employers get Careers emails or do they have to check their profiles to check for candidates?

Tags: discussion, jobs

If someone applies to a Careers job using the Careers 2.0 profile, will it be sent through the employer's email or the email they posted (if they're different)?

Also I am curious, do they have to look back in their Stack Overflow employer account to check for job seekers or do they just get a bunch of emails from Stack Overflow and sift through those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Employers will both get an email at the address they specify and a notification in their Careers account